# Visual Studio Code, Autohide Terminal Code Sending, Ubuntu

Tags: python, r, visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual Studio Code version 1.62.3 on Ubuntu 20.04.03 LTS. I am working with mainly R and Python.

Sending code snippets works fine. My issue is that by default upon sending code to a "hidden" terminal, the termial window automatically opens. I am aware that I can close the terminal window with CTRL + j which also works fine. However I would like to avoid this behavior of having to close the terminal manually and wanted to ask if there is a way to  disable the automatic opening of the terminal upon sending code snippets.

Thus I want the terminal to stay closed by default after receiving code snippets and only open on demand by CTRL + j.

Comment: What do you mean by "sending"?

Comment: sending: executing or to run

Comment: In your JSON Settings, is `r.alwaysUseActiveTerminal` set to "true" or "false"?

Comment: that line does not exist in my .json. only r.rterm.linux: